# How to constrain malloc to a specific region of memory

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, mprotect

Is there anything that:

- Allocates/deallocates/reallocates many variable sized objects without fragmentation (basically what `malloc` does) and
- keeps track of all memory pages used in for these allocations so that I can
- later `mprotect` all of these pages to make them read-only
- preferably without any locking - all access will be single-threaded
- that works on Linux and OS X, preferably with something equivalent on Windows?

I can't think of a way of doing this with standard memory allocation functions. The only strategy that comes to mind is using a custom memory pool instead of `malloc`. So my question is: is there a way to do this without a custom `malloc` or (if there isn't) suggestions on what to use?

I could wrap `malloc` and keep track of all pages it has used pretty easily how do I guarantee that once I have called `mprotect` on these pages `malloc` doesn't try to use memory that is "caught" either before the start or after the end of an allocated block within one of the affected pages?

Comment: what do you mean by "later"? after the process terminates? Do you really mean "pages" (virtual memory) or "frames" (physical memory)?

Comment: Do you only need to allocate memory? Or also to deallocate it? And what's your usecase?

Comment: normal malloc won't work e.g. because for small allocations, pages are shared between multiple things allocated using malloc

Comment: If you are putting your tracking data in your extended `malloc()` allocations: Instead wrap `malloc()`, `free()`, etc. without adding your tracking info to the allocated blocks.  Adding your tracking info there, create a parallel tracking list in a separate memory space.  Then you `mprotect()` calls will not affect your tracking data.

Comment: Are you looking for something like dmalloc, or the Electric Fence malloc debugger, perhaps?

Comment: @Elazar by "later" I mean after some initialization phase the program creates a snapshot of its heap (by marking the pages read-only) and then continues to process requests with reference to this snapshot. I mean pages in the sense in which the man page of `mprotect` uses the term - so I think virtual memory.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson no I'm not looking for a debugging aid. I want to create a complex structure in a region of memory I can later mark as completely read-only. The structure will be built by executing Lua scripts. After initialization, I need to prevent it from being modified because I want to share it across multiple threads without synchronization.

Comment: @thejh I know that pages are shared between allocation (pages are much larger than the average allocation size) - this is the problem with just using `malloc` and tracking which pages are used.

Comment: Do you have a special requirement not to use a memory pool?  What you are trying to do is likely to be complicated.  Are you trying to patch someone else's unmodifiable code that uses malloc, or something?

Answer (score 1):

The open source [Memory Pool System](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps) will allocate memory in operating system page-sized chunks which the MPS does not itself touch.  You can `mprotect` these pages if you like and be certain that they won't be touched by the allocator itself (which keeps all its data structures elsewhere) or by any other memory pool.  If you use the [MVT](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/version/1.111/manual/html/pool/mvt.html) pool class you can also take advantage on [inline lockless allocation](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/version/1.111/manual/html/topic/allocation.html#allocation-points) as well.  [Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows are supported](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/version/1.111/manual/html/guide/build.html#platforms).

Disclaimer: I'm the architect of the MPS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I couldn't use this due to the license restrictions. In the end I decided to use one of the freely available malloc implementations (dlmalloc).

Comment: Good luck, but did you notice "If the licensing terms aren't suitable for you (for example, you're
developing a closed-source commercial product or a compiler run-time
system) you can easily license the MPS under different terms from
Ravenbrook."